# Check locale language in C

Tags: c, locale

I want to check if my system is `zh_TW.UTF-8` or `zh_CN.UTF-8`.

Use the following code, I can tell that it is `UTF-8`.
But, how can I tell whether it is `zh_TW` or `zh_CN`?

```
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   //setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"");
   setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
   printf("%s\n",nl_langinfo(CODESET));
   printf("%s\n",nl_langinfo(CRNCYSTR));
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
printf("%s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, ""));
```

And, read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/clocale/setlocale/).

Comment: I've tried the link example code. get following result  
`Locale is: C  
Date is: Wed Mar  7 17:05:39 2012  
Currency symbol is: 
-
Locale is: LC_CTYPE=zh_TW.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
Date is: Wed 07 Mar 2012 05:05:39 PM CST
Currency symbol is: $`

Comment: Do you know which locale category you want to look at? If you know you want `LC_CTYPE`, change the code to `printf("%s\n", setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ""));`, and the output will be `zh_TW.UTF-8`

Comment: I'm not sure I know.  What's the general case in display purpose?  In my system, I use LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=zh_TW.UTF-8, that let me can type-in Chinese, and display correct.  But, if I release my program, the user often be LANG=zh_TW.UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

On a POSIX-like system, there is a simple way: try the [`locale`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/locale.html) command:

```
system("locale");
```

or

```
FILE *handle = popen("locale", "r+");

size_t readn;
char buf[128];
while ((readn = fread(buf, 1, 128, handle)) > 0) {
    fwrite(buf, 1, readn, stdout);
}
pclose(handle);
```

Comment: -1 this is a terribly unportable way of doing something incredibly portable. See my answer.

Comment: Don't forget to error check the `handle` returned by `popen()`.

Comment: Using `locale -a` gives you information that `setlocale()` cannot give you, namely the list of available locales.  Somehow, I had missed on on the existence of the command, so +1 for making me aware of its existence.  I agree that `setlocale()` is generally better for a program (but not a shell script), but don't forget that the format and contents of the string is implementation defined, and may not be easy to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`setlocale()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html) returns a pointer to a string that contains the locale information.  You can take a copy of it (but may not modify it, and subsequent calls to `setlocale()` may overwrite the previous value).  The string can be used for setting the locale again in future.

```
char *loc_str = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

if (loc_str == 0)
    ...failed to set locale...
printf("LC_ALL = %s\n", loc_str);
```

If you set one category, you get a string back that would allow you to reinstate that category.  You could look at `LC_COLLATE` and see what is set:

```
char *loc_str = setlocale(LC_COLLATE, "");
if (loc_str == 0)
    ...failed to set locale...
printf("LC_COLLATE = %s\n", loc_str);
```

Etc.

It may or may not give you a human-readable value - but at least experiment to see what it in use.

You could also look at the `LANG` environment variable, or the `LC_*` environment variables.